# what is the console application in yii2 framework?

Tags: php, yii2

Application extends from yii\base\Application by providing functionalities that are specific to console requests. In particular, it deals with console requests through a command-based approach

can any one explain that with more examples

Comment: What’s your specific question? PHP can be run from a web browser or through the CLI. Both versions take additional information, URLs and headers for one, command name and arguments for the other, and then perform logic. There’s a deeper dive on the [console here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-console).

Comment: Console can execute PHP scripts via command line or shell script. It does not require web server, only installed PHP. Check out docs https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-console

Answer (score 0):

A console application is an application that uses the installed PHP of the Command Line Interface (CLI) instead of a web server.

Functions of the console application can be called via the yii script by inputting 'php yii' in a terminal inside of the folder where the yii script is installed. (By default this is in the root of your project)

These console application scripts can be run manually by a developer, for example through an SSH connection to the server where your Yii application is installed.
Another commonly used method to execute these console application scripts is by putting them in a [cronjob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).
More information on Yii2 console applications can be found [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-console).